# Adaptive per-user CPU quota/priority in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, cpu, process, scheduling

We have a workstation computer in the office running Win 8.1 where multiple users remotely run cpu-intensive processes at the same time. The problem is that one user can hog the cpu making all operations slow for everyone else. Is there a way to assign a cpuquota pr priority per user or process without wasting cycles on idling? Say user A runs a process at 100% cpu, but when user B logs in, A's process is scaled back enough to allow B, say, 30% cpu time.

Comment: I don't believe what you want is even possible with the setup your using.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Windows desktop OS's allow for multiple concurrent users, Windows desktop operating systems are not currently designed to easily prioritize one user's process over another.

That does not mean this cant be accomplished.  See this article on [CPU rate limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384148%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  Note:  I havent tried this, so I do not know how effective it will be.  In theory, you could write a script that checks how many people are logged in and adjust the users priorities accordingly using the method in the article.  If you were to try this, I would definitely do thorough testing to see how all your applications react.